# Where can I find a full list of indexes on couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

When I run `select * from system:indexes` on couchase, it shows there're 149 docs, but there's not as many indexes in the Indexes list.
So where does couchbase store exhaustive list of indexes?

I've tried researching how indexes are stores on couchbase, but nothing useful has found.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the two lists to see the differences? There might be some indexes that are not user-defined. Or it might be possible that you're only viewing a subset of indexes for a specific scope/collection in the Indexes list.

Answer (score 0):

IP of index node

```
curl -s Administrator:password@127.0.0.1:9102/getIndexStatus |jq '.status[].definition' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/"$/;/g' | sed 's/\\"/"/g'
```